# JavaScript: Clean way to set/remove a bool attribute

Tags: javascript

With Javascript I often have to do something like this:

```js
   if (predicate) el.setAttribute('data-foo', '')
   else el.removeAttribute('data-foo')
```

what I would really like to do is this (nice and DRY):

```js
   el.setBoolAttribute('data-foo', predicate)  // Desired function
```

Its a function I would like to use in the DOM, and web component shadow roots, in many places, so its not really a function I would like to import from a module. Does Javascript have any sort of native way?

Comment: Is there a big difference between setting a boolean to false or removing it? Because your desired function would work for setting to true/false. Wouldn't remove, though but that might be OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Element#toggleAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute):

```js
el.toggleAttribute('data-foo', predicate);
// if predicate is true, the attribute is added
// if it is false, the attribute is removed
```

Comment: Did not know about the 2nd argument. Where has this been my whole life. Thank you!!

Comment: Likewise `classList.toggle(token, force)`  ... so much win.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use a `WeakMap` to map any DOM element to a JavaScript object. Then you are free to use all the power of JavaScript data types:

```js
// One global variable
const domMap = new WeakMap;

// Initialise element-related data
domMap.set(document.body, { foo: true, bar: new Date() });

// Get and set...
console.log(domMap.get(document.body).foo); // true
console.log(domMap.get(document.body).bar); // (current date)
domMap.get(document.body).foo = false;
domMap.get(document.body).bar.setFullYear(2000);
console.log(domMap.get(document.body).foo); // false
console.log(domMap.get(document.body).bar); // Today in year 2000
```